# Google Recaptcha not working with axios

Tags: node.js, recaptcha, axios

I am encountering an error while trying to verify my recaptcha witch axios

```
try{
            let result = await axios.post(
                'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
                {
                    secret: '6LcarRkTAAAAAPDNrruugUg1fJqOJnH-uvVa5KIL',
                    response: response
                },
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    }
                });

            let data = result.data || {};
            if(!data.success){
                throw({
                    success: false,
                    error: 'response not valid'
                })
            }
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
            throw err.response ? err.response.data : {success: false, error: 'verifyCatpcha Error'}
        }
```

I am always getting the error

```
{ success: false,
'error-codes': [ 'missing-input-response', 'missing-input-secret' ] }
```

I tried it with postman and it works fine. Something wrong with my header?

Comment: Maybe need to make GET request. And as i think google captcha needs three params

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to add one more key to your request: `secret`. The error message is caused by missing `response` and `secret` parameters when sending POST request.

**UPDATE**: The POST params in the doc are not JSON, they must be passed as query string. That's why the error says it's missing both `missing-input-response` and `missing-input-secret`

```
axios.post(
  `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${secret}&response=${response}`,
  {},
  {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
    },
  },
);
```

Reference: [Doc](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify)

Comment: as you can see i have been sending the secret and the response

Comment: i've got the same problem!

Comment: @clive-sargeant I updated my answer, please give it a try

Comment: thanks. got it to work but i have to enable cors on my browser else i get: "'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.xxxxxxx' is therefore not allowed access." it now seems that the only way to overcome this error is to use a proxy cors server. so i am now researching how to do that...

Comment: Thanks so much for your help :) 

This certainly confused me at first as I typically use Postman for testing all my requests and then implement them.

Thanks!

Comment: according to document remoteip seems to be missing https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Answer (score 12):

I managed to solve it be adding params.
I will accept [Ryan Wus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471840/ryan-wu) answer cause it is basically the same with different writing.

```
    try{
        let result = await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
            params: {
                secret: '6LcarRkTAAAAAPDNrruugUg1fJqOJnH-uvVa5KIL',
                response: response
            }
        });
        let data = result.data || {};
        if(!data.success){
            throw({
                success: false,
                error: 'response not valid'
            })
        }
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        throw err.response ? err.response.data : {success: false, error: 'captcha_error'}
    }
```

Comment: This is cleaner than passing string templates.

Answer (score 6):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48083886/5426839

> The POST params in the doc are not JSON, they must be passed as query string. That's why the error says it's missing both missing-input-response and missing-input-secret

Not opposite to the highest answer, just shorter syntax:

```
axios.post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', undefined, {
        params: {
            secret: RECAPTCHA_V3_SECRET,
            response: recaptchaToken
        }
    })
```

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.